# Creating table with multiple foreign keys in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this schema that I was trying to create:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS brands (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   name text
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS topics (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   name text
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   name text
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS retailers (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   name text,
    country_id integer,
    foreign key(country_id) references countries(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   category text
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    brand_id integer,
    category_id integer,
   name text,
    description text,
    upc bigint,
    color text,
    size text,
    dimension text,
    weight text,
    foreign key(brand_id) references brands(id),
    foreign key(category_id) references categories(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products_images (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   url text,
    product_id integer,
    foreign key(product_id) references products(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews_sentiments (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    review_date date,
    product_id integer,
    retailer_id integer,    
    topic_id integer,
    reviews_count integer,
    negatives_count integer,
    neutrals_count integer,
    positives_count integer,
    positivity integer,
    foreign key (product_id) references products(id),
    foreign key (retailer_id) references retailers(id),
    foreign key (topic_id) references topics(id)
);
```

All the tables have successfully created, only the last one `reviews_sentiments`

The error that I am getting is the following:

```
ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

If I create the table without the `product_id` foreign key and leaving the two others, it would work .
What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your products table already exists and might not have the id column.
If so, try the following :

```sql
ALTER TABLE "products" ADD PRIMARY KEY IF NOT EXISTS ("id");
```

And run the scripts for review_sentiments.